# What might be the issue I am having with my sorting algorithm for sorting an array of objects?

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I have an array of objects. Each object is being sorted by a string that is a member of the object. Here are the strings that are saved,

```
"Mead Johnson"
"Heartlight Corp Inc"
"Learning Horizons"
"Block Drug Co"
"Block Drug Co"
"Warner Lambert Consumer Healthcare"
"Novartis Consumer Health Inc"
"Bionutrics Health Products Inc"
"Warner Lambert Consumer Healthcare"
"Barilla America"
"Bionutrics Health Products Inc"
```

and here is the output order I get:

```
"Bionutrics Health Products Inc"
"Block Drug Co"
"Block Drug Co"
"Heartlight Corp Inc"
"Learning Horizons"
"Barilla America"
"Mead Johnson"
"Novartis Consumer Health Inc"
"Warner Labert Consumer Healthcare"
"Warner Lambert Consumer Healthcare"
"Biobutrics Health Products Inc"
```

As you can see the list is almost sorted. The code I used is below

```
private void sort(Manufacturer[] manuArray, int left, int right)
{
    int pivotValue;
    if(left < right)
    {
        pivotValue = pivot(manuArray, left,right);
        sort(manuArray, left, pivotValue-1);
        sort(manuArray, pivotValue+1,right);
    }
}

private  int pivot(Manufacturer[] manuArray, int left, int right)
{
    int p = left;
    String pivotName = manuArray[left].getName();
    for(int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
    {
        if(manuArray[i].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(pivotName) < 0)
        {
            p++;
            swap(manuArray, i, p);
        }
    }
    swap(manuArray, p, left);
    return p;
}

private void swap(Manufacturer[] manuArray, int i, int p)
{
    Manufacturer tempManu1 = manuArray[i];
    Manufacturer tempManu2 = manuArray[p];
    manuArray[i] = manuArray[p];
    manuArray[p] = tempManu1;
}
```

I cannot seem to find why the algorithm arbitrarily doesn't sort a few of the items. Any ideas why?

EDIT: I found the problem

my loop was:

```
    for(int i = left + 1; i < right; i++)
```

if needed to be:

```
    for(int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Why would you reimplement quicksort when it is native to Java?

Comment: Yeah we have to create our own.

Answer (score 0):

Try do not sum 1 in the loop for:

```
for(int i = left; i < right; i++)
{
...
```

If not, try to adapt this code to yours. I am sorting by increasing distances instead of alphabetically:

```
public static void ordenarChollos(List<CholloObjeto> chollostemp, int izq, int der) {
    CholloObjeto pivote=chollostemp.get(izq); 
    int i=izq; 
    int j=der; 
    CholloObjeto aux;

    while(i<j){           
        while(chollostemp.get(i).getDistance() <= pivote.getDistance() && i<j) i++; 
        while(chollostemp.get(j).getDistance() > pivote.getDistance()) j--;         
        if (i<j) {                      
            aux = chollostemp.get(i);                 
            chollostemp.set(i,chollostemp.get(j));
            chollostemp.set(j,aux);
        }
    }
    chollostemp.set(izq,chollostemp.get(j)); 
    chollostemp.set(j,pivote); 
    if(izq<j-1)
        ordenarChollos(chollostemp,izq,j-1); 
    if(j+1 <der)
        ordenarChollos(chollostemp,j+1,der); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not following what you suggested in the for loop part of your post.

Comment: I mean in your pivot function, start the for loop from "left", not from "left+1" as a sugestion to try.

Comment: In my function I use while loops. My chollostemp object is the same as your manuArray object. You are using getName and I am using getDistance instead. Alphabetical order / Distance in meters order. 

Where I compare distances inside while statements with > or <=, you should use the compare string java function .

Comment: Even with your for loop change I am still receiving the same problem.